# Cucumber with Selenium and Junit gives : java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: selenium, junit, initialization, cucumber, xstream

I'm trying to run a cucumber test using selenium / java. Based on the console output , I can say for sure that the step definiton file has been found by the feature file , but still , the moment the code enters the @Given block , it errors out with below. I tried my best to know why this error occurs , tried adding xstream jar and many other things , but just cant figure out the exact jar file that I need to add / remove or update.

My Feature File is Below:

```
#Author: your.email@your.domain.com
#Keywords Summary :
#Feature: List of scenarios.
#Scenario: Business rule through list of steps with arguments.
#Given: Some precondition step
#When: Some key actions
#Then: To observe outcomes or validation
#And,But: To enumerate more Given,When,Then steps
#Scenario Outline: List of steps for data-driven as an Examples and <placeholder>
#Examples: Container for s table
#Background: List of steps run before each of the scenarios
#""" (Doc Strings)
#| (Data Tables)
#@ (Tags/Labels):To group Scenarios
#<> (placeholder)
#""
## (Comments)
#Sample Feature Definition Template
Feature: Title of your feature
  I want to use this template for my feature file

  Scenario: Launch the Browser
    Given I initialize the driver
    When I launch the url
    Then I land on the page
```

Console Output Below:

```
Feature: Title of your feature
  I want to use this template for my feature file

  Scenario: Launch the Browser    # src/features/browser.feature:22
    Given I initialize the driver # browser.i_initialize_the_driver()
      java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:117)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:55)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:126)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:82)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
    at ?.I initialize the driver(src/features/browser.feature:23)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @43bd930a
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:807)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:76)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:117)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:55)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:126)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:82)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

    When I launch the url         # browser.i_launch_the_url()
    Then I land on the page       # browser.i_land_on_the_page()
```

My Code Structure:

[image]

My Test Runner Class is below:

```
package cucumbertest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        
        features="src/features",
        glue="stepdefinition",
        plugin= {"pretty","html:target/Cucumber.html"},
        monochrome=true
        
        )


public class TestRunner {

}
```

My Step Definition Class is below:

```
package stepdefinition;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class browser {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    @Given("^I initialize the driver$")
    public void i_initialize_the_driver() throws Exception {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        //throw new PendingException();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ttmanner\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.29.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("Iam in Given");
        
    }

    @When("^I launch the url$")
    public void i_launch_the_url() throws Exception {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        //throw new PendingException();
        driver.get("http://idrw.org/");
    }

    @Then("^I land on the page$")
    public void i_land_on_the_page() throws Exception {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        //throw new PendingException();
        
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().equals("Defence"));
    }

    
    

}
```

My Jar Files are below (Not using Maven , Unfortunately I'm in a specific scenario where I cant use Maven)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using a combination of Cucumber and Java that are not compatible together. You can either downgrade your Java or upgrade your Cucumber version. The latter is probably the better choice.

Comment: which version of java do you recommend I down grade to.Many thanks for your response