# Error while running cucumber feature file via testng

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

**Below is the error i get:**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.5.0
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 5 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 7 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 0 ms.
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\WB584896\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1298892710\testng-customsuite.xml

[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] DynamicGraphHelper.createDynamicGraph() took 3 ms.

[31mFailed scenarios:[0m
[31mModernContentCount.feature:4 [0m# Scenario: To validate the count match between Source and Modern Site
[31mModernContentCount.feature:11 [0m# Scenario: To close the browser and copy output files

2 Scenarios ([31m2 failed[0m)
4 Steps ([31m2 failed[0m, [36m2 skipped[0m)
0m0.088s

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at selenium.testrunner.tests.Smoke.testCucumber(Smoke.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
    at ?.Given User launch the URL(ModernContentCount.feature:5)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @548a9f61
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at selenium.testrunner.tests.Smoke.testCucumber(Smoke.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at selenium.testrunner.tests.Smoke.testCucumber(Smoke.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
    at ?.Given Close the Browser(ModernContentCount.feature:12)

FAILED: testCucumber(To Validate the count match between Source and Modern site)
        Runs Cucumber Feature
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:69)
    at selenium.testrunner.tests.Smoke.testCucumber(Smoke.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at selenium.testrunner.tests.Smoke.testCucumber(Smoke.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
    at ?.Given User launch the URL(ModernContentCount.feature:5)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @548a9f61
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:39)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:820)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:574)
    at cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:530)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams$LocalizedXStream.<init>(LocalizedXStreams.java:50)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.newXStream(LocalizedXStreams.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams.get(LocalizedXStreams.java:29)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at selenium.testrunner.tests.Smoke.testCucumber(Smoke.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.internal.ExitCodeListener@6a282fdd: 0 ms
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@3b90a30a: 61 ms
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@d74bac4: 50 ms
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter@6dd82486: 17 ms
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@43f61afb: 9 ms
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@186cb891: 12 ms
[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@624a24f6: 8 ms
```

**Error denoted line in smoke file:**

```java
    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void testCucumber(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        System.setProperty("environment.reader", "NA");
        **testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());**
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("src/test/resources/Manager/config.xml"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "Windows 10");
        Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("abcd");
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68137060/cucumber-with-selenium-and-junit-gives-java-lang-exceptionininitializererror/68137159#68137159

Comment: In the future, please take advantage of the formatting tools to make your post easier to read.  I've fixed it for you on this one, though.